# How to access a database file with non mdf extension

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-express

Can we access a database file with non-`.MDF` extension using C#?

We are creating a setup project. We don't want the user to know the database details which is installed in the installation folder. So, I have tried renaming the database data file and log file with a random name without any extension.

When I have tried accessing the file from c# we are getting an error like:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database to file D:\SQLExpress\DB\abc123tmp failed. A database of the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located at UNC share.

Can anyone help me solve the issue?

Comment: Where is your relevant code?

Comment: I am getting this error when I try to establish connection to SQL

Comment: Your problem lies in connection string to load MDF file. Provide your current connection string and related code which throwing exception.

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(localDb)\MSSQLLOCALDB;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFilename=D:\SQLExpress\DB\abc123tmp;";

 con.Open();

Answer (score 0):

Start SSMS, connect to (localDb)\MSSQLLOCALDB and look at the Databases attached ... I guess the File you want to attach is already attached under a different name. Detach that instance first and then your Connection should work. It's not possible to attach the same File using different Database names. The File Extension does not matter.

Comment: I have checked from ssms, I have deleted all the files related to the DB, even though we are getting the same error.